# is there a existing way to integrate linux patch utility with Perforce(p4)?patch doesn't automatically do a “p4 edit” on patched files

Tags: patch, perforce

After generating a diff/patch file using

```
p4 diff -du > mypatch.diff
```

perforce command. Am using the linux patch utility to patch the diff onto my new repo/workspace:-

```
 patch -p<n> < mypatch.diff
```

The diff is patched properly however the files doesn't show up upon executing "p4 opened" command. This is expected because I haven't done a "p4 edit" on the files. So the question is, is there a standard way to integrate the patch utility with perforce. For example by installing a plugin, or by providing a argument to patch command? Or should I write my own shell script with alias name patch which will grep for file names from diff file and do a "p4 edit" before actually executing the patch command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do a `p4 reconcile` after applying the patch. You can set up `P4IGNORE` to point to a file that makes the reconcile process ignore `.orig` and `.rej` files.